# lighttpd: redirect traffic from http to https on *.domain.tdl

Tags: subdomain, lighttpd, wildcard-subdomain

I am using Lighttpd with a snipped i've found on the net. How to redirect all subdomains of a given domain to https without touching other domains or subdomains of domains?

Currently i am doing this on the needed subdomains:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^sub\.(.*)" {
            url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://sub.%1/$1" )
    }
}
```

I would love to have it the over way around. Is it possible? Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you'd want to take, say, `example.com` and redirect not for `example.com`, but for all of its subdomains?

This should do it:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.*\.example\.com)$" {
  url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1/$1" )
}
```

Comment: Thanks allot. `example.com` could have been included, but i don't really need it. So your snippet fits perfectly! Thanks

Comment: sadly i can't do +1 yet :(

Comment: Great!  To include `example.com`, just need to add a question mark to the expression in the right place: `^(.*\.?example\.com)$`